# temporarily disable mysql remote access

Tags: mysql, linux

I need to disble remote access during nightly mysql maintenance on Linux server so that no one can query the database during that time.  I can't do SERVICE MYSQL STOP because then I couldn't do what I needed to do (truncate and rebuild a couple tables).  Is there a way to turn off external access for a short time?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean denying connections other than localhost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a great way without touching anything in the OS:

Step 1) Export all users to SQL file like this:

> mysql -h localhost -u root
>   -p rootpassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM
>   mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql
>   -hlocalhost -uroot -prootpassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > /root/MySQLGrants.sql

Step 2) Disable all users except root@localhost

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE CONCAT(user,host) <> 'rootlocalhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step 3) Perform your maintenance

Step 4) Reload the Grants

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p rootpassword < /root/MySQLGrants.sql
```

Give this a Try !!!!

PS

service mysql restart --skip-networking

would still be the simplest and fastest way plus logging off all connections before maintenance

just run service mysql restart after your maintenance

Comment: actually, that sounds good ... the maintenance I need to do is from a local script ... why is it a bad idea?

Comment: I thought what I said originally was a bad idea because I thought mysql needed to up continuously.

Comment: oh ... well if service mysqld restart--skip-networking does a graceful restart (that is, wait for active queries to finish), then it would be perfect.  I do need mysql to be up for the maintenance but down for the users.

Answer (score 2):

[Since 5.7.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-5.html) there's an "official way" to deal with that:

> MySQL Server now supports an “offline mode” with these
>   characteristics:
>
> Connected client users who do not have the SUPER privilege are
>   disconnected on the next request, with an appropriate error.
>   Disconnection includes terminating running statements and releasing
>   locks. Such clients also cannot initiate new connections, and receive
>   an appropriate error.
>
> Connected client users who have the SUPER privilege are not
>   disconnected, and can initiate new connections to manage the server.
>
> Replication slave threads are permitted to keep applying data to the
>   server.
>
> Only users who have the SUPER privilege can control offline mode. To
>   put a server in offline mode, change the value of the new offline_mode
>   system variable from OFF to ON. To resume normal operations, change
>   offline_mode from ON to OFF. In offline mode, clients that are refused
>   access receive an ER_SERVER_OFFLINE_MODE error.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the login credentials used by the remote apps?

Firewall the MySQL port so it can't be accessed by the remote apps?

Comment: good ideas ... but I was hoping for something slightly smoother.  Closing the port may damage a query.  And revoking and reestablishing privileges is a little more work than I intended.  I was hoping there was some obscure mysql command that did the trick.

Comment: @xivix How can closing a port damage a query?

Comment: I could end up closing a port in the middle of a select or an update thus not giving the requestor feedback of result.  It's just not clean.

Answer (score 0):

There are some another method to temporary disable access to MySQL database during maintenance.
Edit /etc/mysql/my.conf'

Change bind-address to:
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Restart MySQL:
service mysql restart --skip-networking

Nobody will access MySQL server from remote until you have change bind-address to original value and restart MySQL again.