# Temporarily disable mySQL access

Tags: mysql, permissions, acl

I have a mySQL DB, which everynight reloads a DB in it (that's to say, a `DROP DATABASE` and then an import mysql DB). I have a single account that currently has read-only access to the DB (`GRANT SELECT ON` fruitdb.* to 'someUser'@'localhost').

What I would like is a way to disable the account while the refresh is happening. However I don't want to use a server-admin level account on mySQL (it's a script that will reload the DB, and I don't want have a service-admin account's password in that script).

I did read [temporarily disable mysql remote access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707311/temporarily-disable-mysql-remote-access), however that won't work, as it means exposing the root password. In addition it's just one account I want to block, not all of them.

Comment: Is it Linux? Just an idea, the script might be impersonificated to special user, it would have its own properties in its home directory that nobody else could read. The script would need +s privilege so it would be run under owner and so it could read its config that executing user cannot read. http://computernetworkingnotes.com/managing-file-system-security/sticky-bit.html

Comment: Yes it is under linux. I was trying to avoid using the sudoers file if possible.